# How I run individual java file in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am a java beginner, the first java IDE I downloaded was Visual Studio Code, it was very easy to use and everything is auto configured. But it kind overheats my laptop all the time, so I want to try IDEA, so far it's a very good experience, except when I open a java file and tried to run it in IDEA, it always pops out this run configuration window and I don't understand how to configure it. In visual Studio Code I can open any java file any time and run without any issues, but now I have to go through creating projects every time. Is there any solution for this?

[image: Run configuration window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Command-line

To run a single file, there is no need for an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

In Java 11 and later, the `java` tool at the command-line can both compile and execute a single-file Java class. See [*JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330).

If your class named `HelloWorld` were in a file named `HelloWorld.java`, on a console type:

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

To be clear: The `java` command-line tool really only *executes* Java apps, while the `javac` command-line tool *compiles* Java source code. As a convenience, the `java` tool was enhanced to effectively call `javac` on your behalf for a single-file.

## *JShell*

If you just want to run a few lines of Java, try [*JShell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JShell), the [REPL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) tool bundled with Java 9 and later.

See:

- [*Java Shell User’s Guide*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jshell/index.html) by Oracle
- [*JEP 222: jshell: The Java Shell (Read-Eval-Print Loop)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222)

[Search to learn more](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java%20JShell&t=osx&ia=web) and [find tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java%20JShell%20tutorial&t=osx&ia=web).

## *BlueJ*

Using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) such as [*IntelliJ*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), [*NetBeans*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), or [*Eclipse*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) can be a daunting task for the new student of Java. Those IDEs are heavy-duty tools designed for professional programmers.

I recommend using an IDE designed for beginners. [BlueJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJ) comes to mind, designed specifically for educational purposes. BlueJ makes getting started with Java easier.

If you insist on using IntelliJ, read on.

## If using IntelliJ, define a project

IntelliJ is not designed to work with single files. IntelliJ expects you to work within a project.

I strongly recommend learning the basics of [*Maven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) to create and drive your new project. By defining your project in Maven, the configuration is independent of any one IDE. You can move your project between major IDEs such as IntelliJ, NetBeans, and Eclipse.

Maven is also very useful for downloading needed libraries ("dependencies") that you may want to leverage in your work. And Maven is good at packaging your Java app as a JAR (or WAR or EAR).

In IntelliJ, choose "New Project". In the *New Project* window, click the *Maven* item on left. Check the *Create from archetype* box. Scroll the list to find item for `org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart`. Under that, choose the "RELEASE" item. Click *Next* button.

In *Name* field, enter something like `MyFirstProject`. Click *Next* button.

On the Maven settings page, just click *Finish*.

Wait a moment for IntelliJ to download some stuff and configure your project. Eventually you should see a *BUILD SUCCESS* message in the *Run* pane.

You will also see a `pom.xml` file displayed. The [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) contains your settings for Maven to run your project, in [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) format.

Change the `<maven.compiler.source>` and `<maven.compiler.target>` elements to the version of Java you are using. The current version is Java 17.

After editing the `pom.xml`, look for a little floating windoid with a tiny Maven icon. Click the icon to have Maven process your changed POM. Wait a moment.

In the *Project* pane, navigate to the `App` file. There you see code to print “Hello World!”. Let's run that code now. **Click the green triangle button on the left**, in the gutter, next to the `main` method line. A pop-up menu appears offering a *Run* item. Choose that item to run the app immediately.

[image: screenshot of green arrow in gutter next to main method]

Down in the *Run* pane, you should see the results, the `Hello World!` text.

At this point you can add your single file to the `org.example` package seen in the *Project* pane.

By the way, you can change that package name by context-clicking and choosing *Refactor* > *Rename…*.

Later, learn to use the [*Run/debug configurations*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html) feature of IntelliJ.

Know that you need not create a new project for each time you want to do a little experiment. Create one project for such experiments. Keep adding new `.java` class files for each experiment. Delete old class files you no longer need.

---

Eventually, I suggest updating the versions of various items in your POM. The *QuickStart* archetype is not configured for the latest versions (for reasons I cannot fathom).

And when you learn about unit testing, replace JUnit 4 in the POM with [*JUnit Jupiter (Aggregator)*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) to use JUnit 5. One of the benefits of using Maven is that you can easily switch out dependencies such as going from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5.

Comment: I think Maven is too much for a Java beginner.  I love Maven, but it's not where I'd start.

Comment: @duffymo I agree, but when engaging with an major IDE such as IntelliJ using Maven is the wisest path I believe. I tried to be explicit in the steps to minimize the learning necessary. For easier onboarding, the user should be using [*BlueJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJ) instead of IntelliJ/NetBeans/Eclipse. I will add a mention of that to the Answer.

Comment: I believe you're wrong.  Why?  He's writing lab classes that have no dependencies.  What good does Maven do?  The problem is that he doesn't know IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks, that is a lot efforts you put here. I guess I would still have to go back to VS code, something that I actually know how to use. All I need is a IDE that can run any individual java file at any time and with a terminal window to input, like the way I used to write python, java seems is a lot more different language.

Answer (score 1):

From how the file icon looks:

[image]

your file is not recognized as the part of the sources of your project. Check the project settings to ensure that source directories are correctly set.

I'd also recommend you to look up and follow the conventions for the directory structure of java projects.

Once you've fixed the problem with sources, you'll see "run" icon next to your class, `main` method, or when you're right clicking the file.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE needs to know what's called the entry point of the program, i.e. where to start running your code. That's what the "Edit Configuration" window is wanting you to do.
If your file "Lab3.java" is in a package, make sure to fully specify that in the field you have in red. Otherwise without knowing how your project is structured (as the other answer alludes to), it's difficult to pinpoint what we're missing here.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your IntelliJ project, add a directory `/src` right at the root of your project.  Right click on that folder and tell IntelliJ that you wish to mark it as a source root.  The directory should turn blue in color.

Put your packages under `/src`.  IntelliJ will know that those are Java files.

When you want to run a class with a main method, choose Run->Edit Configurations.  Tell IntelliJ that you want to add an Application.  It should prompt you with the classes that have `main` methods in them.  You'll have no trouble running them.

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven or Graddle. Make sure the project is configured with the build tool enabled and integrated, it will do basic things automatically. If you are not sure, please create a new project and add your files in. Steps:

1. Open the IDE
2. New Project
3. Choose from the left side bar "Maven" or "Graddle"
4. Give it a name and the location in your machine.
5. Click Finish
   Now you have the project ready. You need the appropriate method to run in java. A main class. In IntelliJ you can just type "main" and the auto-complete will add it for you, make sure you inside the curly brackets of the class {}. [More info about the main class](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_class_methods.asp). You seem to have this nailed down.

Lastly make sure you have a JDK installed in the IDE. I am pretty sure this is your issue here, make sure to use one of the option IntelliJ provides. A full guide from the developers is **[here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#jdk)** and should satisfy your needs. I would suggest OpenJDK for a beginner, because that served me well at the beginning, at the end of the day its your choice.